# How to set field in previous step as JSON Output File Name in Pentaho?

Tags: json, pentaho, pdi

I want to use a Concatenated field as the Json output filename in my Pentaho Data Integration transformation, but as long as I don't see any "Accept field as filename" option, I don't know how to make this happen.

Could someone help me to sort it out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was to create the filenames in a previous job step and assign the value to a variable. Then I used this variable within the Json Output filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose "Output value" as the operation, then use a Text File Output step to write out the value in the specified field to a filename contained in a field. You may need to add the filename field after the JSON Output step, in order to have a single filename associated with each row from a JSON Output step